# htmlspecialchars removes formatting

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

i'm calling the htmlspecialchars function inside another function in a class, but when i do this, even though the data displays, it removes all formatting showing the data in a single line.

this is the code:

```
class Name {
    . .. .
    public function h($s) 
    {
    echo htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES);
     }

    public function formatQuotes($row)
    {

    return "<p id=\"ab_quotes\">" . this->h($row['cQuotes']) . "</p>"
    . "<p id=\"ab_author\">" . this->h($row['vAuthor']) . "</p>";             
    }

}
```

if i remove the reference to htmlspecialchars function, it displays the data as it should.

**UPDATE:**

this is the css which i've applied:

```
p#ab_quotes{
    font-size: 22px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    }

p#ab_author {
    font-size: 15px;
        position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: #EB3B55;
    }
```

there is no html within $row['cQuotes'] and Author variables. it is the css formatting which is removed when the htmlspecialchars is implemented.

another thing, that i noticed was that if i removed `ENT_QUOTES`, it works, but again with it, it removes the formatting. why is this so?

Comment: Please provide some sample of input data.

Comment: Do you have HTML within your `$row['cQuotes']` and `$row['vAuthor']` variables?

Comment: Isn't that the way it is supposed to happen?

Comment: Also, function h needs to *return* data, not echo it

Comment: it doesn't read the html, ignoring `<p>` and all the css formatting which i've done. it just displays the data in a line without any spacing.

Comment: @fusion - it isn't supposed to read HTML. It should return a string, which placed into HTML will display as is (i.e. you will see a `<p>`, not a new paragraph)

Comment: it's working now. i think @Yacoby, your solution about `return` and not `echo` was the right one. how do i mark your answer as the accepted one?

Comment: @fusion I have added my comment as an answer so you can accept it (if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that the function `h()` needs to return the data rather than echo it (based on how you are using the result of `h()`)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by formatting? If you mean HTML code, htmlspecialchars will replace these characters crucial to HTML with their entities:

- '&' (ampersand) becomes '&'
- '"' (double quote) becomes '"' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- ''' (single quote) becomes ''' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
- '<' (less than) becomes '<'
- '>' (greater than) becomes '>'

(taken from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Of course none of the formatting will have effect then. That's the point of htmlspecialchars().

Comment: without using the object oriented approach, the function htmlspecialchars works and it displays all the *css* formatting. 

but using classes, it does not work.